# Does socat support SOCK_SEQPACKET for Unix domain socket?

Tags: linux, socat

Consider the following setup where one instance of [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) pipes data from `stdin` to a unix domain socket, and the other instance reads that data from the unix domain socket and writes it to `stdout`:

Client:

```sh
(while true; do echo "hello"; sleep 1; done) | socat STDIN UNIX:test.sock
```

Server:

```sh
socat UNIX-LISTEN:test.sock STDOUT
```

This setup works as expected, where the server prints `hello` to `stdout` at an interval of 1 second. Is there a way with `socat` to use the [SOCK_SEQPACKET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) socket type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon further investigation of the [man page](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html), I learned that `SOCK_SEQPACKET` is supported by `socat`:

> socktype=
> Sets the type of the socket, specified as second argument to the socket() or socketpair() calls, to  [int]. Address resolution is not affected by this option. Under Linux, 1 means stream oriented socket, 2 means datagram socket, 3 means raw socket, and **5 seqpacket** (stream keeping packet boundaries).

Client:

```sh
(while true; do echo "hello"; sleep 1; done) | socat STDIN UNIX:test.sock,socktype=5
```

Server:

```sh
socat UNIX-LISTEN:test.sock,socktype=5 STDOUT
```